# How to get information that coroutine has been destroyed/cancelled?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I would like to know when launched coroutine has been destroyed. Is it possible ?
Coroutine needs to be launched in Repository class in Android Application class scope and when app will be closed I need to do some clean up.

```
fun doSomeWorkGlobally() {
   applicationScope.launch { //Application class scope
      val streamListener = object : StreamListener {
          override fun dataSnapshot(val data: Data) {
              dataSharedFlow.tryEmit(data)
          }
      }
      registerToListener.register(streamListener)
      //unregister callback, do clean up work when this coroutine is destroyed (?)
   }
}
```

If it would be possible to do something similar like awaitClose with callbackFlow it will be great.

P.S. callbackFlow is not 100% the case for my situation, I'm wondering if I can do something similar in code above.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Inside your program assign a variable to your coroutine task like this.

```
fun doSomeWorkGlobally() {
   val job:Job=applicationScope.launch { //Application class scope
      val streamListener = object : StreamListener {
          override fun dataSnapshot(val data: Data) {
              dataSharedFlow.tryEmit(data)
          }
      }
      registerToListener.register(streamListener)
      //unregister callback, do clean up work when this coroutine is destroyed (?)
   }
}
```

then use this

```
fun Job.runOnCanceled(context: CoroutineContext = DefaultDispatcher, handler: suspend (Job) -> Unit) {
    val job = this
    launch(context) {
        job.join()
        if (job.isCancelled)
            handler(job)
    }
}
```

Ref:https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/coroutine-how-to-get-notification-when-job-is-canceled/6861

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you are looking for is [`Job.invokeOnCompletion`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-job/invoke-on-completion.html), which you would use like this:

```
val job = applicationScope.launch { ... }
job.invokeOnCompletion {
    // code that runs when the job is done, whether by completing normally,
    // having been cancelled, or due to an error
}
```

Comment: applicationScope is a scope created in android Application class so when I close app invokeOnCompletion should be called but It doesn't